# problems connecting to port 3306 mysql workbench with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, port

I'm trying to learn the apache / mysql / php stack bundled with XAMPP. I can't connect to the MySQL server using the MySQL workbench:

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

Thinking it's a port problem, I check the port directly in Terminal with the command `telnet 3306`:

> telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

Obviously the problem isn't with the Workbench, but something to do with the port connection itself.

I'm using:

- OS 10.8 Mountain Lion
- XAMPP 1.7.3
- MySQL workbench 5.2.47

Comment: 1) is mysqld even running  2) can you connect with simply mysql -uroot -p    3)  what does netstat -tulpn report for 3306

Answer (score 19):

Sorry all, I'm posting my own question and answer. I had this problem and it nearly destroyed me because I could not find the correct answer anywhere on the interwebz. I finally overcame it, and wanted to post my findings in case it helps another befuddled traveler.

It turns out when you install XAMPP and choose to run the security routines, it automatically turns on a setting in the MySQL preferences to block connections on port 3306 from localhost. To fix this, open my.cnf in the xampp folder xamppfiles/etc. Look for the setting "skip-networking" which tells mySQL to block the port 3306. Comment this out by adding a pound sign so it is "#skip-networking". Now, the telnet command should work, and you should be able to use the Workbench.

Hope this is helpful for somebody!If it fixes your problem, give me a shout at @mrcheeks3185.

Comment: Why you need mysql workbench when mysql already included in the xampp package. That is why the port conflicting because of the 2 mysql server in ur system

Comment: I found my `my.cnf` file thanks to @CrsCaballero's answer but skip-networking was already commented...

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem but I solved it.

I changed the  MySQL workbench port to 3307 in the file below

`C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini`

and keep the default port 3306 for XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

for mac you should create only a user with password and grant access(in my case a I use root with password) and turn on ip address and use that address to connect with a client like navcat or workbench I use XAMPP 7.3

[ip address network given by XAMPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYIve.png)

[connection config in navcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBcb8.png)

[test connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54zEy.png)

Comment: The only solution work for me. Actually XAMPP install MySQL in VM, so connect it via IP address show in XAMPP. There is no MySQL server on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have `my.cnf` you can first go to `xampp->mysql->bin->my.ini`, copy
the contents of the file, next create `my.cnf` (in the `bin` folder) and paste the content to the file you just created.

This works for me. I had the same problem. Now I can use both Xampp and Workbench on one PC.
There is an issue: when you start workbench you get some warning that some features may not work properly since database is not fully compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I found that file after mount the image disk created for xampp, there you can find `new_disc_mounted/etc/my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

If changing ports won't work. What I did, I just make sure both XAMPP and MySQL Workbench don't start the server at the same time. Just go to MySQL Workbench, Select Server > Startup/Shutdown > Shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

its due to different version of xampp, open log file and check last status of mysql there is showing error find it or remark/change it

Answer (score 0):

Actually XAMPP and MySQL workBench might be using same port an are conflicting "3306" in so you are getting that error

Please try changing the workBench's default port number to other number and try again

Comment: This answer seems to be a duplicate of multiple others answers